# Given a dictionary with lists of strings as their values, how would you retrieve all keys where the list contains a string unique to all other lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization

As an example if the dictionary was this:

```
myDict = {"egg sandwich":["bread", "lettuce", "mayo","egg"], 
          "sad sandwich":["bread","lettuce","mayo"],
          "ham sandwich":["bread","lettuce","mayo","ham"],
          "healthy sandwich":["lettuce"],
          "breakfast sandwich":["bread","egg","mayo"]}
```

The function should return "ham sandwich" , since it is the only sandwich that contains an ingredient (ham) unique to a comparison of all other lists.

Comment: 'healthy sandwich' should be return too, right?

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA Why?  The first three sandwiches also contain "lettuce".

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA, John Gordon is correct. The function should only return keys that contain a value unique to ALL other lists.

Comment: Yes, I read it wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
def get_unique_item(d):
    all_ingredients = [y for x in d.values() for y in x]

    output = []
    for name, ingredients in d.items():
        for ingredient in ingredients:
            if all_ingredients.count(ingredient) == 1:
                output.append(name)
                break

    return output

myDict = {"egg sandwich":["bread", "lettuce", "mayo","egg"], 
          "sad sandwich":["bread","lettuce","mayo"],
          "ham sandwich":["bread","lettuce","mayo","ham"],
          "healthy sandwich":["lettuce"],
          "breakfast sandwich":["bread","egg","mayo"]}


print(get_unique_item(myDict))
```

Output:

```
['ham sandwich']
```

---

Basically, we create a list of all occurrences of all ingredients, and for each sandwich, we check if there are any ingredients which only occur once.

---

If you really want to, you can make it a one-line list comprehension:

```
[name for name, ingredients in d.items() if any([y for x in d.values() for y in set(x)].count(i) == 1 for i in ingredients)]
```

Comment: is this a fast solution? The dictionary I am working with has about 100,000 items with the lists containing anywhere between 10 to 40 elements.

Comment: I really don't know - I guess test it with 100 first, then maybe 1000, etc... Don't use the list comp in that case :)